# Understand algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

Can somebody explain why complexity of the algorithm bellow is O(log N)?
This is one of the questions from https://www.interviewbit.com and their explanation/tip is not clear to me (see bellow the code block).

```
    int a = 0, i = N;
    while (i > 0) {
        a += i;
        i /= 2;
    }
```

`1. Notice that in every iteration, i goes to i / 2`  <--- got that

`2. So, after x iterations, i will be N / 2^x` <--- I agree, but how did I suppose to figure that out (it doesn't come to me just from the thin air).

`3. We have to find first x such that N / 2^x < 1 OR 2^x > N` <-- understand it from the previous step. And also understand that is solution from this step is `x = log N`.

So, entire questions for me is why is it i=N/2^x after x iterations?

Comment: Integer exponentiation can be defined as repeated multiplication.  So multiplying by `1/2`, `k` times, is by definition the same as multiplying by `(1/2)^k = 1/2^k`.

Answer (score 0):

Start off with some arbitrarily large number, like 1028 :D

Then repeatedly divide until you get down to 0.

The value of `i` at the top of the loop each time is:

1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 0

Then look at it backwards: you may as well start at i = 1 and multiply by 2 each time until it hits 1024.

So this is the number of times you need to multiply by 2 to get n, which is log2(N)

Answer (score 0):

Add the variable `ni = floor(lg2(i))`. At every loop of the `while` statement variable `i` goes from `i` to `i' = i/2`, and therefore `ni` goes to `ni'`, which satisfies

```
ni' = floor(lg2(i'))
    = floor(lg2(i/2))
    = floor(lg2(i) - lg2(2))
    = floor(lg2(i) - 1)
    = floor(lg2(i)) - 1
    = ni - 1
```

This shows that `ni` decreases by `1` at every loop. And since `ni` starts at `floor(lg2(N))`, there must be `floor(lg2(N))` loops in the `while`.